# javafx catch more then one key press event at the same time

Tags: javafx, keypress

I want to catch the event when we press in 2 keys of keyboard (ctrl + here)
to zoom in tabview  here's my code, so far i can just catch only the ctrl, i dont know how to catch the event when we hold ctrl then click on + ( or at least click on ctrl then c every time to zoom) , i had idea of key combination:

final KeyCombination keyCtrlPlus = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.PLUS, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);
but i don't know how to do it in the addEventFilter(). Any help please?

```
m_TabView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent e)
    {
       if (keyCtrlPlus.match(e))
       { 
       //function to zoom tabview 
          zoomOut(e);
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it. It's a little simpler, in my opinion. Not to mention, this **specifically** answers Coeur's question; which was, how to check KeyCombination inside of an **addEventFilter** method ...

This is in my controller class...

```
@FXML private TextField textField;

final KeyCombination keyShiftTab = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.TAB, KeyCombination.SHIFT_ANY);

@FXML
public void initialize()
{
    textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyShiftTab.match(e))
            {
                doSomthing();
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Works like a champ for me. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a listener, register all key presses of the key pressed event in a bitset and evaluate and unregister them in the key released event.

Something like this, supports multiple keys including modifiers:

```
import java.util.BitSet;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private BitSet keyboardBitSet = new BitSet();

    Scene scene;
    Label label;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox();

        label = new Label();

        root.getChildren().add(label);

        scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyPressedEventHandler);
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyReleasedEventHandler);

        // init label text
        updateKeyboardStatus();
    }

    /**
     * "Key Pressed" handler for all input events: register pressed key in the bitset
     */
    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyPressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            // register key down
            keyboardBitSet.set(event.getCode().ordinal(), true);

            updateKeyboardStatus();
        }
    };

    /**
     * "Key Released" handler for all input events: unregister released key in the bitset
     */
    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            // register key up
            keyboardBitSet.set(event.getCode().ordinal(), false);

            updateKeyboardStatus();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Detect all keys and show them in the label
     */
    private void updateKeyboardStatus() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Current key combination: ");

        int count = 0;
        for( KeyCode keyCode: KeyCode.values()) {

            if( keyboardBitSet.get(keyCode.ordinal())) {

                if( count > 0) {
                    sb.append( " ");
                }

                sb.append(keyCode.toString());

                count++;
            }

        }

        label.setText(sb.toString());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ronald @ Stephan actually i used KEY_RELEASED , and I modified the key combination to this       final KeyCombination keyCtrlShiftPlus = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.EQUALS, KeyCombination.SHIFT_ANY,KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);   it works fine .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```
this.scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if(key.length()>0){
            if(key.toString().equals(keyCombination1)){
                System.out.println("Key Combination 1 pressed");

            }else if(key.toString().equals(keyCombination2)){
                System.out.println("Key Combination 2 pressed");
            }else if(key.toString().equals(keyCombination3)){
                System.out.println("Key Combination 3 pressed");
            }

            key.setLength(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Taken from:

https://code.google.com/p/javafx-demos/source/browse/trunk/javafx-demos/src/main/java/com/ezest/javafx/demogallery/KeyCombinationDemo.java

Comment: yes, thank u I changed KEY_PRESSED by KEY_RELEASED and I verify every time if the key combination match .. I figured out that the problem is : when u click in plus key it actually gives equals not + ...that's why it doesn't work, I want to know is there any way to make a key combination for three keys? i mean : ctrl shift +

Comment: I think you can only add additional modifiers, so Str+Shift+Alt+...+ "+"
http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/input/KeyCodeCombination.html